# With strictNullChecks enabled, can I assertions without needing the Non-Null Assertion Operator?

Tags: typescript

tl;dr: I'd like to be able to use an `assert` utility to check that a value is non-null, and then have Typescript understand that the value in non-null. I have `strictNullChecks` enabled, and I'd prefer not to use the non-null assertion operator.

According to [the typescript docs](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/strictNullChecks.html#non-null-assertion-operator), one way I can use assertions is the following, using the non-null assertion operator (slightly modified from the docs):

```
// Compiled with --strictNullChecks
function assertEntity(e?: Entity) {
  // Throw exception if e is null or undefined
}

function processEntity(e?: Entity) {
  assertEntity(e);
  let s = e!.name;  // Assert that e is non-null and access name
}
```

I prefer to use assertions as infrequently as possible, however, since they're prone to misuse. I'd prefer to do something like this:

```
// Add a good return type to assertEntity to clarify that it may throw
function assertEntity(e?: Entity): void | never {
  if (!e) {
    throw Error('Entity is falsy!');
  }
}

function processEntity(e?: Entity) {
  assertEntity(e);

  // At this point I'd like typescript to know that e is truthy
  let s = e.name;
}
```

The docs say that the non-null assertion operator is to be used "where the type checker is unable to conclude that fact". My question is, is there some way I can help the type checker correctly conclude that `e` is not null?

I'm already aware of a few ways of doing this, which require a bit more boilerplate than I'd like. For example, I can use a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), but that can result in lots more levels of indentation:

```
function checkEntity(e: any): e is Entity {
  return e && e.name;
}

function processEntity(e?: Entity) {
  assertEntity(e);

  // This checkEntity call seems superfluous, since I'm already
  // calling assertEntity above.
  if (checkEntity(e)) {
    let s = e.name;
  }
}
```

Or I can do it this different way, which also solves the type problems, but which requires some misleading code, since it has a spurious early return:

```
// Note that assertEntity is now a user-defined type guard, because of
// the `e is Entity` return value.
function assertEntity(e?: Entity): e is Entity {
  if (!e) {
    throw Error('Entity is falsy!');
  }
  return true;
}

function processEntity(e?: Entity) {
  // I can make assertEntity into a user-defined type guard, but then this
  // code looks as if it might have an early return, when in fact it will throw
  // if `e` is falsy.
  if (!assertEntity(e)) {
    return; // This return is impossible to reach
  }
  let s = e.name;
}
```

Comment: There is no syntax for custom assertions, `if (!assertEntity(e)) return;` is the shortest you will get for now. I am sure there is a GitHub proposal to support this

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17760

Comment: Yah, I was afraid there wasn't a way to do it, since the docs recommend using the non-null assertion operator. Ah, well.